# Angular JS REST API GET Not displaying data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Nooby Question here.  I have test sales data in a JSON Format and want to display the data in a table using Angular JS.

Here is the Angular Code.

```
var SalesDataApp = angular.module("SalesDataApp", []);

app.factory("services", ['$http', function ($http) {
var serviceBase = '/api/sales';
var obj = {};
obj.getCustomers = function () {
    return $http.get(serviceBase);
};
return obj;
}]);
app.controller('SalesDataController', function ($scope, services) {
services.getCustomers().then(function (data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    $scope.customers = data;
});
});
```

I know theres better ways of doing this but im just delving into Angular... Heres my HTML..

```
<div ng-controller="SalesDataController">
<table class="table table-striped" >
 <tr><th>ID</th>
 </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat="a in salesData">
         <td>{{a.Index}}</td>
     </tr>

 </table>
 </div>
```

Ive done a test to see if angular is working and thats a winner, but the code isnt displaying anything.  Exactly where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Do you ever reference `customers` in the HTML?

Comment: @tymeJV yeah.  Ive changed the salesData over to customers and still not a single thing :-(

Comment: Can you post what `console.log($scope.customers)` looks like in your `.then()`

Comment: @tymeJV ok so really nooby here.  help me out on the console.log??  (Maybe I should just stick to Back End development and not move into UI's)

Comment: Haha - after you assign the `$scope.customers = data;` call - do `console.log($scope.customers)` - and to see your console, press F12 (most browsers anyways) - or find it in the dev tools. It works WAAAAY nicer than `alert`

Comment: this is what I got..  'app' is undefined SCRIPT5009

Comment: Ahh - yeah - `var SalesDataApp = angular.module("SalesDataApp", []);` - should be `var app = angular.module("SalesDataApp", []);` - since you reference `app` rather than `SalesDataApp` when defining controllers and services.

Comment: ok.  Changed it, reran and got this !!!  [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/ng/areq?p0=SalesDataController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined  This is somethign to do with the controller?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any variable named salesData in your controller, probably you need to refer it as customers in the html.

```
<div ng-controller="SalesDataController">
<table class="table table-striped" >
 <tr><th>ID</th>
 </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat="a in customers">
         <td>{{a.Index}}</td>
     </tr>

 </table>
 </div>
```

Also change your app name

**From:**

```
var SalesDataApp = angular.module("SalesDataApp", []);
```

**To:**

```
var app = angular.module("SalesDataApp", []);
```

Comment: yeah jsut changed it and still nothing

Comment: console.log($scope.customers) inside your controller

Comment: Seriously nooby here at front end development...  whats the console.log?  Sorry.  This is my first foray into front end development and Im a little out of my depth here.

Comment: ok i think its better if you create the issue in plunker or jsfiddle

Comment: just used the dev tools and this is the error I got 'app' is undefined

Comment: oh have you mentioned the ng-app = "SalesDataApp" in html?

Comment: Yes.  Its in the _SalesLayout Layout here <body ng-app="SalesDataApp">

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module("SalesDataApp", []);

app.factory("services", ['$http', function ($http) {
  var serviceBase = '/api/sales';
  var obj = {};
  obj.getCustomers = function () {
    return $http.get(serviceBase);
  };
  return obj;
}]);
app.controller('SalesDataController', function ($scope, services) {
  services.getCustomers().then(function (data) {
    console.log(data); //changed
    $scope.customers = data;
  });
});
```

<del>I added .json to the serviceBase string. I am making the assumption that you have the sales.json file in the correct location relative to this application.</del>  You should now see data in the console. Depending on how it is formatted in the JSON file it may now be in the UI as well. If it is not you will need to set $scope.customers properly using the data structure displayed in the console.

Comment: sales.json file?  Its an API so why does this need a json file? sorry for the stupid question but I thought API's delivered the data dynamically.  I write this using Knockout and didnt need a json file here so could you please explain?

Comment: I made the assumption is was a local file. If it is a service you are good to go.

Comment: This is so frustrating!!!!  I've got no console Log, No errors and its not handling my data!!!  I really dont understand this at all. On IIS Express this worked fine with Knockout but now, with Angular, its not running or doing anything! How can this be?